# Dropbox Developer app for public access

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to create "public developer app" for Dropbox (Business Api)?

I created a Dropbox account for "MyOrganisation" and I set up a Developer App (MyOrgApp) and retrieved appId and appkey. This App is using Oath endpoints to get the access token. When I login with MyOrganisaiton admin account credentials, I get the accesstoken which I can use to do Api calls for MyOrganisation. It works fine.

My question is that will I be able to use this App (MyOrgApp) to do Api calls for another organisation "Organisation2"? Or Dropbox apps are more like Private Apps where each Organisation needs to have their own app to make api calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox Business API doesn't make a distinction between "public" and "private" API apps exactly. You can use your registered Dropbox Business API app to operate on multiple different teams, but you first need to get "production" access. You can find more information about that here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#production

Comment: Should those multiple teams need to be in one organisation (MyOrganisation which has the Drop box app configured) or is it possible to have teams in different organisations (Different Dropbox Business companies), for an example Organisation 2, which does not have a Dropbox App configured, can I get an accesstoken using the MyOrganisation App?

Comment: For an example in GoogleApps you can create an App where any one with a google account can use the app, not only the account which has the Google App configured (e.g. accessing Google Drive). Is the same thing possible for Dropbox Business Api?

Comment: What do you mean by "organization"? You may be referring to what I'm calling "teams". When I refer to a "team" I am already referring to the single unit of the Dropbox Business product that a company would buy. Once in production mode, a Dropbox Business API app can be linked to multiple different teams.

Comment: Ok, that's makes sense. I thought 1 teams in one organisation. As Organisations I was referring to different Dropbox Instances, thanks Greg, "Organisations = Teams".